# R: Optimize index-wise comparisons that depend on other vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have four vectors

```
x, y, z, w
length(x) = length(y) = length(z) = length(w) = 5000
```

and I want to do the following:

Take the vector 'w' and run through each index 'i' from 1 to 5000. For each index 'i', find the index 'j' in 'x' which is closest y[i]. Then, take that index 'j', and compare if w[i] > z[j] for all i and j(i) .... by j(i), I mean that j depends on i.

I only want to know if that's true or not, I don't want to compute the corresponding is and js.

I have fitted this procedure using a for loop, and I use which.min to find the index 'j'. This is very slow. How to optimize?

---

Example:

```
z <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
w <- c(2,3,2,5,5)
x <- c(200,300,400,500,600)
y <- c(300,300,200,500,600)
```

So, based on above, we have the following 5 comparisons:

```
w[1] > z[2]   (because y[1] is closest to x[2])
w[2] > z[2]    (because y[2] is closest to x[2])
w[3] < z[1]    (because y[3] is closest to x[1])
```

Notice that now we already know w[i] is not greater strictly than z[j], so we can stop here. Output should then be

```
"FALSE"
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution *does* compute the j's and makes all of the comparisons.

```
all(w > z[apply(abs(outer(x, y, `-`)), 2, which.min)])
```

depends on what you need for fast. On my machine, this took just under a second to run on an example with 5000 x values.

```
system.time(
     all(w > z[apply(abs(outer(x, y, `-`)), 2, which.min)]))
            user           system          elapsed 
0.77000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.97000000000116
```